# implementing "1<<(val-1)"; shift with carry; assembler; aarch64; arm64

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, arm64

I'd like to do calculation like 1<<(val-1) where val is any value in the range of 3 to 12.
It could be done in 3 operations like

```
mov x0, #1
sub val, #1
lsl x2, x0, val
```

Another idea is to set Carry flag and rotate with carry. In this case it would be done in two operations because 'val' shouldn't be subtracted.

The problem is it seems that arm64 do not support rotation th/ carry.
Does anybody have ideas how to put this code into 2 ops?
Thanks.

Comment: You woun't be doing it in 2 instructions anyway, as you would need to set the carry flag.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why not? one instr to set carry (which is like '1' in position [-1]), second instr is shift left which put bit from [-1] position to the [val-1]. The problem it that comparing w/ arm32 which allow shift th/ carry flag, arm64 has only addition, subtraction and negate instruction which support carry.

Comment: You would need to set the target to 0 and the carry to 1.

Comment: @WeatherVane "set the target to 0" is not necessary. aarch64 has wzr/xzr which are zero always registers.

Comment: Every compiler I've tried generates the same (or equivalent) 3 instructions for the given code, and they're cleverer than I am. Sure, you could do it in two instructions _if_ there was a "rotate with carry" instruction, but hey, you could also do it in one if there was a "shift by one less than the value in the register" instruction. Different ISA, different code.